# Get filepaths for uniqe files in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have following folder  structure:

```
/a/b/c/d/e.txt
/a/b/c/e.txt
/a/b/m.txt
```

I want the output to be

```
/a/b/c/d/e.txt
/a/b/m.txt
```

Any of the path to e.txt would work. So far, I am able to filter out the unique files, but I am loosing value of full path.

```
find . -name '*.txt' |  awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | uniq
```

Output is

```
e.txt
f.txt
```

Is there any way using awk, sed or any other command to print the full path in above scenario?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F/ '!seen[$NF]++' file

/a/b/c/d/e.txt
/a/b/m.txt
```

`seen` is an associative array with key as `$NF` (last field).